# memberOf attribute in Active Directory does not contain all user groups

Tags: active-directory, jndi

I have made an application, where I want to bring all the user accounts and their memberships in the Active Directory Environment. I came to know that a user in Active Directory has `memberOf` attribute which stores the `distinguishedName` of the groups of which a user is a member.

However, when I checked out and found the `memberOf` isn't all the groups of which user is a member of. For example, it only contains few `distinguishedName` of the groups in other domain of same forest.

**Am I missing something ?** Is there some configuration which has to be done on Active Directory.

Please note, I am using Java JNDI for bringing the users form the active directory.

Comment: Did you query the global catalog?

Comment: @Tomer No, I queried the individual domains. Due to certain restrictions, I can't query Global Catalog. Btw would that be beneficial ?